# as. double()/ as.numeric() not working

Tags: r, abstract-data-type

I want the program to read the data as double float but when **I use as.double and as.numeric it changes the data itself**.
Original data
[Original data is in fractions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l57oU.png)

After applying as.double to each column separately and combining to form a dataframe, the data starts looking like this
[Changed data values after applying as. double()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctXlJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your data are probably `factor` (not `character`). 
To convert column `x` to `numeric` use `as.numeric(levels(x))[x]`

[This](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f) can also help.